# Kivy Import Error: No module named 'kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple'

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to import `TouchRippleBehavior` in Kivy using this:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior
```

However, it throws:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple'
```

Currently I am using Python 2.7, 3.5.2, and 3.6.4(pyenv). I tried on all versions but got same error.

Comment: Do you have other Kivy imports that work?

Comment: Yes all other imports are working absolutely fine.

Comment: What is your version of kivy?

Comment: Did you install Kivy master? This module is not in any stable release.

Comment: I am using 1.10.0 version.